# Ctr+s event on clicking a hyperlink

Tags: javascript

I have a hyperlink, when i click this link Ctr+s event should be fired which results in prompting to save the webpage. How can i call Ctr+s event when clicking a link I needs this in javascript or jquery

Answer (score 0):

add `onClick`  event same as `Ctrl`+`S`. Don't return false in `onClick`

Comment: $('#id').click( function(){ //do smth ;} );

Answer (score 0):

I believe this works in ie.

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);"  onclick="document.execCommand('SaveAs');"
 >Save this page</a>
```